# vsphere powercli commands to check for cpu and memory utilization in terms of percentage

Tags: powercli

How do I get the CPU utilization and memory utilization in terms of percentage of the hosts?

```
Get-VMHost | Export-Csv "C:\checks.csv"
```

this gives me the output in terms of Mhz

```
Get-VMHost | Export-Csv "C:\checks.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a couple PowerShell tricks in order to perform that task.

First, calculated properties. Get-VMHost doesn't have an existing property consisting of the CPU or Memory usage percentages. It does, however, contain both the usage and total amounts which we can use to create a percentage from. In order to display it, we'll make use of what's known as a calculated property which will allow us to create a custom property, that's in the form of a hashtable, where we perform that calculation at runtime.

Example: `@{Name = 'CpuUsage'; Expression = {$_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz}}`

Second, we'll need to convert the calculated value into something easier to understand. We can use a format specifier that's part of the `ToString` method.

Example: `@{Name = 'CpuUsage'; Expression = {($_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz).ToString("P")}}`

In the end, your code should look a bit like the following:

```
Get-VMHost | select Name, ConnectionState, PowerState, @{Name = 'CpuUsage'; Expression = {($_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz).ToString("P")}}, @{Name = 'MemoryUsage'; Expression = {($_.MemoryUsageGB / $_.MemoryTotalGB).ToString("P")}}, Version | Export-Csv "C:\checks.csv"
```